# How do you update gc_grace_seconds using cassandra-cli?

Tags: cassandra

What is the command to update a column family and alter its `gc_grace_seconds` value using `cassandra-cli`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On `cassandra-cli` is without "seconds"

```
UPDATE COLUMN FAMILY cf with GC_GRACE = 86400; //one day
```

Comment: i updated my columnfamily as above to delete the rowkey, but rowkey remains same

Answer (score 36):

For CQLSH

```
alter table <table_name> with GC_GRACE_SECONDS = <timeout>;
```

e.g:

```
alter table yawn with GC_GRACE_SECONDS = 3600;
```

where yawn is our table name and 3600 is an hour;

Comment: CLI approach doesn't work, we get an error message to use CQLSH now, hence this answer.
Cassandra 2.0.
HTH

Comment: Please check the value of max_hint_window_in_ms if the hinted_handoff is enabled

Comment: This is the correct solution even on Cassandra 3.11.

Answer (score 1):

```
use ks;
update column family cf with gc_grace_seconds = 864000;
```

Comment: it giving this java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient.ColumnFamilyArgument.GC_GRACE_SECONDS

Comment: See the accepted answer, it's meant to be gc_grace not gc_grace_seconds.