# JanusGraph query failure due to Cassandra backend tombstone exception

Tags: cassandra, graph-databases, titan, janusgraph

I have raised a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/1675) regarding this as well. Pasting the same below.

- JanusGraph version - janusgraph-0.3.1
- Cassandra - cassandra:3.11.4

When we run JanusGraph with the Cassandra backend, after a period of time, the JanusGraph starts throwing the below errors and goes in to an unusable state.

JanusGraph Logs:

> 466489 [gremlin-server-exec-6] INFO
>   org.janusgraph.diskstorage.util.BackendOperation - Temporary exception
>   during backend operation [EdgeStoreKeys]. 
>   Attempting backoff retry.
>   org.janusgraph.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: 
>   **Temporary failure in storage backend** at io.vavr.API$Match$Case0.apply(API.java:3174) 
>   at
>   io.vavr.API$Match.of(API.java:3137) at
>   org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLKeyColumnValueStore.lambda$static$0 (CQLKeyColumnValueStore.java:123)
>   at io.vavr.control.Try.getOrElseThrow(Try.java:671) at
>   org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLKeyColumnValueStore.getKeys (CQLKeyColumnValueStore.java:405)
>
> Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException:
>   Cassandra failure during read query at **consistency QUORUM (1 responses
>   were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)** 
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException.copy(ReadFailureException.java:130)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException.copy(ReadFailureException.java:30)

Cassandra Logs:

> WARN [ReadStage-2] 2019-07-19 11:40:02,980 ReadCommand.java:569 - **Read
>   74 live rows and 100001 tombstone cells** for query SELECT * FROM
>   janusgraph.edgestore WHERE column1 >= 02 AND column1 <= 03 LIMIT 100
>   (see tombstone_warn_threshold)
>
> ERROR [ReadStage-2] 2019-07-19
>   11:40:02,980 StorageProxy.java:1896 - **Scanned over 100001 tombstones
>   during query** 'SELECT * FROM janusgraph.edgestore WHERE column1 >= 02
>   AND column1 <= 03 LIMIT 100' (last scanned row partion key was
>   ((00000000002b9d88), 02)); query aborted

Related Question:
[Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069563/cassandra-failure-during-read-query-at-consistency-local-one-1-responses-were-r)

Questions:

1) Is Edge updates are stored as a new item causing tombstones ?. (since janus is a fork of titan).
[How to increment Number of Visit count in Titan graph database Edge Label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36542748/how-to-increment-number-of-visit-count-in-titan-graph-database-edge-label/36544160#36544160)
https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/934

2) What is the right approach towards this. ?

Any solution/indications would be really helpful.

**[Update]**

1) Update to the edges didn't cause tombstones in the JanusGraph.

2) Solutions:
   - As per the answer, reduce the gc_grace_seconds to a lower value based on the deletions of edge/vertex.
   - Also can consider tuning the "tombstone_failure_threshold" in cassandra.yaml based on the needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Cassandra, a tombstone is a flag that indicates that a record should be deleted, this can be occur after a delete operation was explicitly requested, or once that the Time To Live (TTL) period expired. A record with a tombstone will persist for the time defined in the `gc_grace_seconds` after the delete operation was executed, by default it is 10 days.

Usually running `nodetool repair janusgraph edgestore` (based on the error log provided) should be able to fix the issue. If you are still getting the error, you may need to decrease the `gc_grace_seconds` value of your table, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526379/how-do-you-update-gc-grace-seconds-using-cassandra-cli).

For more information regarding tombstones:

- https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html
- [Tombstone vs nodetool and repair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49644528/tombstone-vs-nodetool-and-repair)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped to understand on the gc part. We didn't do a lot of edge deletion in this case. Do you have any idea on edge update causing deletion/re-creation of edges causing tombstones to surface ?